# How can I apply a different wrap to every menu item?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I was trying to create a custom menu in TypoScript and my idea is to have a `div` for each menu item.

#### Example

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu {
   entryLevel = 0  
   1 = TMENU
   1 {
      NO.allWrap = <div id="forsideknap">|</div> |*| <div id="butikker">|</div> |*| <div id="nyheder">|</div> |*| <div id="arrangementer">|</div> |*| <div id="avis">|</div>
   }
}
```

I have created 5 pages, and only 3 of them are getting their `div`. There are 3 identical. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the `optionSplit` concept, which itself has many different options. It might cause confusion when used for the first time. You unintentionally defined the **first**, the **middle** and the **last** part of your wrap by using the `|*|` separators:

```
first element |*| middle element(s) |*| last element
```

If there is more then one middle element, they all get the middle parameter ("butikker"). And everything from the third `|*|` on is ignored.

What you wanted is a simple sequence of different wraps. This is achieved by using the `||` separator:

```
1st element || 2nd element || 3rd element || 4th element || 5th element || etc.
```

In your case:

```
NO.allWrap = <div id="forsideknap">|</div> || <div id="butikker">|</div> || <div id="nyheder">|</div> || <div id="arrangementer">|</div> || <div id="avis">|</div>
```

Note that you can combine the separators if you have more complicated structures.

Read more:

- on the [TYPO3 wiki page about optionSplit](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/optionSplit)
- on [TYPO3 Docs](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ObjectsAndProperties/Index.html#objects-optionsplit)
- [German tutorial on optionSplit in an HMENU / TMENU](http://www.brainworxx.de/brainlife/2011/11/11/typo3-menu-mit-unterschiedlichen-farben-und-klassen-optionsplit/)

Comment: +1 :) is it possible same things in inner anchor tag to each and every class different?

Comment: @GhanshyamGohel, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I am really apologies for bad explanation. I meant that : each and every anchor tad had different class like =>

NO.ATagParams = class="first" || class="popup-text" || class="popup-text" || class="last" 

It's works for me. Thanks that's the concept from your answer :) +1

Comment: Cool. I added two helpful links to the answer.