# Wrap every x item in tmenu

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

```html
<div class="nav nav_main">
    <ul class="level-1">
        <li class="level-1 norm uid_2"><a class="level-1 norm" href="company/at-a-glance/"><span>Company</span></a>

            <div class="level-2-wrapper-outer">
                <div class="level-2-wrapper">
                    <div class="level-2-wrapper-inner">
                        <ul class="level-2">
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="company/at-a-glance/"><span>At a glance</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="company/culture-and-values/"><span>Culture and values</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="company/culture-and-values/#c24">History</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="company/culture-and-values/#c25">Corporate culture</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="company/uhlmann-worldwide/"><span>Uhlmann worldwide</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="company/uhlmann-worldwide/#c231">Germany</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="company/uhlmann-group/"><span>Uhlmann Group</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="company/uhlmann-group/#c29">visiotec</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" target="_blank" href="company/lieferanten-portal/"><span>Lieferanten-Portal</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="level-1 norm uid_3"><a class="level-1 norm" href="solutions/capsules-tablets/"><span>Solutions</span></a>

            <div class="level-2-wrapper-outer">
                <div class="level-2-wrapper">
                    <div class="level-2-wrapper-inner">
                        <ul class="level-2">
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="solutions/capsules-tablets/"><span>Capsules, tablets</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="solutions/capsules-tablets/#c40">Blister machines</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="solutions/vials-ampoules-syringes/"><span>Vials, ampoules, syringes</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="solutions/vials-ampoules-syringes/#c64">Blister machines</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="solutions/blister-bottles/"><span>Blister, bottles</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="solutions/blister-bottles/#c75">Cartoners</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="solutions/blister-bottles/#c76">Stretch-banding machines</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="solutions/cartons-cases/"><span>Cartons, cases</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="solutions/cartons-cases/#c83">Stretch-banding machines</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="solutions/automation-and-software/"><span>Automation and software</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="solutions/automation-and-software/#c94">PDA &amp; SCADA</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="solutions/inspection-systems/"><span>Inspection systems</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="solutions/inspection-systems/#c98">BottleChrom</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="level-1 norm uid_4"><a class="level-1 norm" href="products/blister-machines/"><span>Products</span></a>

            <div class="level-2-wrapper-outer">
                <div class="level-2-wrapper">
                    <div class="level-2-wrapper-inner">
                        <ul class="level-2">
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="products/blister-machines/"><span>Blister machines</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="products/blister-machines/#c109">Blister machine B 1240</a></li>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="products/cartoners/"><span>Cartoners</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="products/cartoners/#c123">Cartoner C 130</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="products/blister-lines/"><span>Blister lines</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="products/blister-lines/#c130">Blister line BEC 300</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="products/end-of-line-packaging-machines/"><span>End-of-line packaging machines</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="products/end-of-line-packaging-machines/#c133">Stretch-banding machines</a></li>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="products/bottle-lines/"><span>Bottle lines</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="products/bottle-lines/#c144">Bottle line IBC 120</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="products/feeders/"><span>Feeders</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="products/feeders/#c148">For solid dose products</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="products/competences/"><span>Competences</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="products/competences/#c158">Containment</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="level-1 norm uid_5"><a class="level-1 norm"   href="services/advice/"><span>Services</span></a>

            <div class="level-2-wrapper-outer">
                <div class="level-2-wrapper">
                    <div class="level-2-wrapper-inner">
                        <ul class="level-2">
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="services/advice/"><span>Advice</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="services/advice/#c170">Quote and order management</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="services/support/"><span>Support</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="services/support/#c174">Telephone support</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="services/on-site-services/"><span>On-Site Services</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="services/on-site-services/#c177">Response time</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="services/spare-parts/"><span>Spare parts</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="services/spare-parts/#c180">Spare parts availability</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="services/format-parts/"><span>Format parts</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="services/format-parts/#c184">Format and tool sets</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="services/upgrades-and-rebuilds/"><span>Upgrades and rebuilds</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="services/upgrades-and-rebuilds/#c186">Electrical upgrades</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="services/automation-and-software/"><span>Automation and software</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="services/automation-and-software/#c191">PDA &amp; SCADA</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="level-2">
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="services/training/"><span>Training</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="services/training/#c194">Operator training</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="level-2 norm"><a class="level-2 norm" href="services/validation-and-calibration/"><span>Validation and calibration</span></a>
                                <ul class="level-3">
                                    <li class="level-3 norm"><a class="level-3 norm" href="services/validation-and-calibration/#c198">Validation of new machines</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Based on question [Menu: wrap every X item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14485225), how can I wrap every x element if I don´t know the exact count of menu elements?

If I use [the answer of chrisBerlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14496872) the problem is that it only works with e.g. 3 elements.

But with a dynamic count of child's per parent it outputs a not valid code.
How can I solve this? My code shows 3 levels of a HMENU. I need the x-wrap in level 2. I use 7 elements per row.

On my page the first element has e.g. 5 child´s. So the `<ul class="level-2">` didn´t get closed.

```
tmp.nav_main = COA
tmp.nav_main{
    10 = COA
    10{
        10 = HMENU
        10{
            wrap = <ul class="level-1">|</ul>
            entryLevel = {$t3d_navigation.nav_main_entryLevel}
            excludeUidList = {$t3d_navigation.nav_main_excludeUidList}
            1 = TMENU
            1 {
                IProcFunc = user_tmenulinebreak->main
                expAll = 1
                NO{
                    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1 norm uid_{field:uid}">|</li>
                    wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
                    ATagParams = class="level-1 norm"
                    stdWrap.wrap = <span>|</span>
                }
                CUR < .NO
                CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1 click uid_{field:uid}">|</li>
                CUR.wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
                CUR.ATagParams = class="level-1 click"
                CUR = 1
                ACT < .CUR
                ACT = 1
            }
            2 < .1
            2 {
                wrap = <div class="level-2-wrapper-outer"><div class="level-2-wrapper"><div class="level-2-wrapper-inner">|</div></div></div>
                expAll = 1
                NO{
                    wrapItemAndSub = |*|<ul class="level-2"><li class="level-2 norm">|</li> || <li class="level-2 norm">|</li> || <li class="level-2 norm">|</li> || <li class="level-2 norm">|</li> || <li class="level-2 norm">|</li> || <li class="level-2 norm">|</li> || <li class="level-2 norm">|</li></ul>|*|
                    ATagParams = class="level-2 norm"
                }
                CUR.wrapItemAndSub = |*|<ul class="level-2"><li class="level-2 click">|</li> || <li class="level-2 click">|</li> || <li class="level-2 click">|</li> || <li class="level-2 click">|</li> || <li class="level-2 click">|</li> || <li class="level-2 click">|</li> || <li class="level-2 click">|</li></ul>|*|
                CUR.ATagParams = class="level-2 click"
                ACT < .CUR
                ACT = 1
            }
            3 < .1
            3 {
                wrap = <ul class="level-3">|</ul>
                expAll = 1
                NO{
                    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-3 norm">|</li>
                    doNotShowLink = 1
                    after{
                        cObject = TEXT
                        cObject{
                            typolink{
                                parameter = {field:pid}#{field:uid}
                                parameter.insertData = 1
                                ATagParams = class="level-3 norm"
                            }
                            data = field:title
                        }
                    }
                }
                CUR{
                    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-3 click">|</li>
                    doNotShowLink = 1
                    after{
                        cObject = TEXT
                        cObject {
                            typolink{
                                parameter = {field:pid}#{field:uid}
                                parameter.insertData = 1
                                ATagParams = class="level-3 click"
                            }
                            data = field:title
                        }
                    }
                }
                ACT < .CUR
                ACT = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my special case I need 1-7 items in a `<ul class="level-2"></ul>` an if there are more than 7 a new row must start with the next 8-14 elements. If there are more than 14 a new row.

Comment: Best show us the HTML code you want to get finally

Answer (score 2):

[Read the docs](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ObjectsAndProperties/Index.html#objects-optionsplit) it gives a lot of clues, the valid syntax for `optionSplit` is:

```
 first-element(s) |*| middle-element(s) |*| last-element(s)
```

- The priority is `last`, `first`, `middle`, which means that only `last` segment will be used if you have one item,
- if there will be two items it will be order `first, last`
- and if you'll have 3 or more items there will be `first, middle(s), last`

each segment can have *numbered subsegments* divided by `||`.

You are using numbered subsegments only in the middle part, you need to fix it.

Other thing is that the optionSplit MUST be valid in all situations, when there's only 1, 2 or 3+ items available, the way you used it causes that there are situations when `ul` is unclosed in other words you need the correct statement on **each** part or subpart of the optionSplit...

**Anyway**, `optionSplit` is nice but tricky technique, it was invented many years ago to add possibility for style manipulation by some factor when there was no any reliable JS library, currently I would use jQuery and/or new CSS features for doing this, just generate plain menu and then add required classes to every-x element. ie.:

- [Like this using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260337/1066240)
- [Like this using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462301/1066240)

Comment: Gotta love `optionSplit` :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forget 1 small but important thing in my question. Could you please recheck(Marked with today´s date 08.04.2015)?